# SerializableException in JSF

Tags: java, jsf

I am dealing with JSF2.0.

I received this error message

> Jul 19, 2011 11:19:47 AM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager doLoad
>   SEVERE: IOException while loading persisted sessions: java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: edu.umn.gis.mapscript.mapObj
>   java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: edu.umn.gis.mapscript.mapObj

what should I do ?

regards

Answer (score 1):

> java.io.NotSerializableException: edu.umn.gis.mapscript.mapObj

It's telling that the class `edu.umn.gis.mapscript.mapObj` is not serializable. You need to make sure that it `implements`[`Serializable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). This is required when you're using JSF view and session scoped beans in a webapp which runs on a webserver which in turn saves sessions to disk in order to survive server restarts or to share with other servers in a cluster.

So, fix it accordingly:

```
package edu.umn.gis.mapscript;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class mapObj implements Serializable { // <--- Here.

    // ...

}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367) state that classnames should start with an uppercase. I strongly recomment do fix it as well. Rename `mapObj` to `MapObj` (or preferably to something more self-documenting, the "Obj" suffix makes very little sense).

Answer (score 0):

One of the objects you are storing in your session (or one of it's members) does not implement `Serializable`.

Answer (score 0):

All of your SessionBeans (and their Members) must implement `Serilizable` to be distributed around the cluster or stored into the Database!